# How to add padding-x to inside echarts?

Tags: angular, echarts

I using echarts to create a chart in angular. I want the chart to be completely stuck to the edges of its parent and have no padding outside of chart.

I using this options:

```
this.options = {
  grid: {
    width: '100%',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zlevel: 0,
    z: 0,
    containLabel: false
  },
  xAxis:[
    {
      type: 'category',
      boundaryGap: false,
      inverse: false,
      nameGap: 0,
      silent: true,
      z: 3000,
      axisLabel: {
        inside: true,
        color: '#333333',
        fontFamily: 'VazirFD',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 500,
        hideOverlap: true,
        margin: 30,
        rotate: 0,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        baseline: 'bottom',
        opacity: 1,
        padding: 0,
      },
      data: response.ordersByMonth.map((item: any) => item.shamsi_month),
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      position: 'left',
      axisLabel: {
        inside: true,
        color: '#333333',
        fontFamily: 'VazirFD',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 500,
        hideOverlap: true,
        margin: 20,
        rotate: 0,
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        baseline: 'top',
        opacity: 1,
        padding: 0,
      }
    },
  ],
  series: [
    {
      stack: 'counts',
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: 'top',
        distance: 10,
        color: '#00BAE3',
        fontFamily: 'VazirFD',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 500,
      },
      type: 'line',
      clip: true,
      areaStyle: {
        color: '#00BAE3',
      },
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#00BAE3',
        opacity: 1,
      },
      data: response.ordersByMonth.map((item: any) => item.order_count),
    },
  ],
}
```

The chart created with the above settings is as follows.
[The chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWW9p.png)

But the example of the diagram that the user interface designer gave me is this
[Target design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9WNC.png)

Comment: I dont think echarts is adding padding at all. You can adjust positions of basically all elements and the grid according to your needs. If you want to add padding to the div element which is used by echarts, you can do so with plain javascript/html.